# Red Hat Linux NTP Inconsistent Values

Tags: redhat, ntp, ntpdate

Recently I am experiencing NTP high delay and offset values on my server.

```
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.161.50.254   .SLK.            1 u  962 1024  377   23.942   -2.157   0.819
+10.147.50.253   .SLK.            1 u 1001 1024  377   26.628    2.991   0.245
```

However, when I query sync details manually, values are way different.

```
$ ntpdate -q  10.161.50.254
server 10.161.50.254, stratum 1, offset -0.001250, delay 0.04601
 5 Mar 11:14:37 ntpdate[29876]: adjust time server 10.161.50.254 offset -0.001250 sec
```

In the first output delay is about 24 seconds, while in the second one it's less than 1 sec. This is the same for offset value. I want to know which output is valid. If the second output is more precise, why is it not showing the same in the first output.
Can anyone explain what causes such difference, which one is valid and should I refer to?

(our service is quite sensitive to time, and such a discrepancy would result in abnormal reports, such as negative service usage duration time)

Comment: They're really not that different. Could you be more precise about what you specifically think is a problem?

Comment: In the first output delay is about 24 seconds, while in the second one it's less than 1 sec. This is the same for offset value. I want to know which output is valid. If the second output is more precise, why is it not showing the same in the first output.
(our service is quite sensitive to time, and such a discrepancy would result in abnormal reports, such as negative service usage duration time)

Comment: It's not 24 seconds, it's 23.942ms one way which is perfectly consistent with 46.01ms round trip.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the delay is the time in milliseconds:

http://www.clock.org/ntp/debug.html

That link details a bit about how to read the output. However, 24ms seems about correct depending on how fast your network is. You need to account for the output in `ntpdate` as well:

https://superuser.com/questions/393426/how-inaccurate-is-my-system-clock-on-unix

This details that `ntpdate -q` is reporting in seconds. 46ms is about the same time as the delay in `ntpq -p` output.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments and answers have pointed out, offset from `ntpdate` is in seconds, whilst `ntpq` displays them in milliseconds.  So there's no real discrepancy in your offsets (which is the important thing).  Your time is in fairly close sync.  But there's still a discrepancy in the delays reported.

I did some tests of delay to my server's peers and got the following:

- peer 1 (stratum 1 BeagleBone Black on my local LAN): 0.02689 s via `ntpdate`, 0.598 ms via `ntpq`, avg 1.032 ms via `ping` - difference between `ntpdate` and `ntpq`: 26.292 ms
- peer 2 (public stratum 1 server about 1000 km away): 0.04485 s via `ntpdate`, 18.662 ms via `ntpq`, avg 18.379 ms via `ping` - difference between `ntpdate` and `ntpq`: 26.188 ms
- peer 3 (public stratum 1 server across the Pacific Ocean): 0.21938 s via `ntpdate`, 193.844 ms via `ntpq`, avg 207.875 ms via `ping` - difference between `ntpdate` and `ntpq`: 25.536 ms

My conclusion: `ntpdate` is somewhat inefficient and adds a fixed overhead of about 25-26 ms on average (on my machine), and that `ntpd` and/or the Linux UDP stack is usually slightly more efficient than `ping` and/or the Linux ICMP stack.

Comment: That is a good clarification. Thank you.